# How to upload a file to jenkins pipeline job as build parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to upload file as  a build parameter as apart of jenkins pipeline job, I tried File parameter but, it is not uploading file. there is nothing in console logs, what am I missing?

configure looks like this,

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the file extension?

Comment: this is a yaml file

Comment: in you File location, put the path as `data/<file-name>.yaml` file will be stored in data directory

Comment: still couldn't see the file uploaded

Comment: is the `data` directory created? Check root of your workspace

Comment: No, data directory was not created, I tried to ls my workspace ${env.WORKSPACE} and there was nothing

Comment: Just to be clear, the file will be only uploaded if you click on `build` you are building the job right?

Comment: That's correct, I didn't see this file in workspace

Answer (score 1):

`fileParam`is not directly reachable from job, because it's not uploaded into the workspace.
Furthermore, there is another difference between jobs built on master or on slaves (i.e. when job is built on slaves, file mush be copied through channel)

Here is a sample of dsl to create job that upload file and send it through e-mail:

Pipeline parameters definition:

```
def job = pipelineJob('MAIL_WITH_UPLOADED_ATTACHMENT') {
    parameters {
        ...
        fileParam('ATTACHMENT', 'Fichier à uploader et attacher à l\'e-mail')
        ...
    }
}
```

Declarative pipeline DSL:

```
def createFilePath(path) {
    if (env['NODE_NAME'] == null) {
        error "envvar NODE_NAME is not set, probably not inside an node {} or running an older version of Jenkins!";
    } else if (env['NODE_NAME'].equals("master")) {
        return new hudson.FilePath(null, path)
    } else {
        return new hudson.FilePath(jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getComputer(env['NODE_NAME']).getChannel(), path)
    }
}

def getFileParamFromWorkspace(fileParamName) {
    def paramsAction = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(ParametersAction.class);
    if (paramsAction != null) {
        for (param in paramsAction.getParameters()) {
            if (param instanceof FileParameterValue) {
                def fileParameterValue = (FileParameterValue)param
                if (fileParamName.equals(fileParameterValue.getName())) {
                    def fileItem = fileParameterValue.getFile()
                    if (fileItem instanceof org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem) {
                        def diskFileItem = (org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem)fileParameterValue.getFile()
                        def filePath = createFilePath(env.WORKSPACE + '/fileparam/' + fileItem.getName())
                        def destFolder = filePath.getParent()
                        destFolder.mkdirs()
                        filePath.copyFrom(diskFileItem)
                        return 'fileparam/' + fileItem.getName()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ''
}

pipeline {
    stages {
        stage ('Mail with uploaded attachment') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def filename = getFileParamFromWorkspace('ATTACHMENT')
                    emailext to: "${params.RECIPIENT_EMAIL}",
                        subject: "${params.SUBJECT} (via ${env.JOB_NAME} ${currentBuild.currentResult})",
                        body: """${currentBuild.currentResult}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME} build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}
                        |
                        | More info at: ${env.BUILD_URL}""".stripMargin(),
                        attachmentsPattern: filename
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```